# What does it mean if my wireframe looks like this? (Discontinuous lines)

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edges, wireframe

I'm trying to make a tent, but I just noticed that when I see the wireframe of my object it looks like a messy mesh

[image: tent's wireframe]

However in edit mode things are better

[image]

Why is that the wireframe looks like that? I know it's probably something I've been doing wrong.

Comment: you'll need to enable the 'draw all edges' option, see the accepted answer of the link above

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks, I thought there was something wrong with the mesh, not that it was an option I had to enable.